# Google display language

Tags: google

I recently downloaded the TOR browser. Upon using it for the first time, Microsoft locked me out of my e-mail account and my Google search home page was changed from U.S. to France. I seem to have resolved the Microsoft account issue, but I'm wondering how to reset Google so that it knows my language, and how to avoid these issues moving forward. I like the idea of TOR, but if it screws everything up, what's the point?

Comment: dont use Google. Use Startpage or DDG

Answer (score 3):

Google uses your geoip location to provide  a webpage with that language. If you get Google.com in French that means you're exiting from an exit node in France. To solve this try to use https://encrypted.google.com/?gl=us or just  https://www.google.com/?gl=us

Comment: Alternatively, `?hl=en`...or whatever your preferred language.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you suggesting these specific urls for Google in lieu of simply google.com? I understand that TOR uses different "layers" to obscure a user's identity; but if it delivers your information to exit ports that software and services (like Google) cannot associate with an origin that is at least generally correct, TOR does not seem like a practical way to surf the web. Unless, of course, you use TOR strictly for specific things that you want hidden. I'm scared to access my online banking with TOR, because if I do, my bank will probably think my account has been hacked!