# Tor browser opens a certian url in French

Tags: settings

Type in www.yahoo.com and it opens in french instead of English as other urls do. How do I make yahoo.com open in English?

JD

Comment: There is a similar question with an explanation already: [Google display language](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/14199/114)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's much more related to how the remote site is working rather than Tor

Answer (score 1):

Click in the little onion in the left of the nav, you'll see "Tor Circuit for this site", the last country, in your case, France, is the country  that "you are", I mean, your IP, for this you see yahoo.fr
In yahoo page, in the right upper corner, you can see a flag, click there and change the country.